# Save keras trained model with custom objects

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.10

I am facing a problem when loading a trained keras model which I have included a custom metric.
The metric is dice_coef:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
        """
        # Code from https://www.kaggle.com/toregil/a-lung-u-net-in-keras In[7]
        Function to calculate dice coefficient

        Parameters
        ----------
        y_true : numpy array of actual masks
        y_pred : numpy array of predicted masks

        Returns
        -------
        dice coefficient

        """
        y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
        y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
        intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
        return (2. * intersection + K.epsilon()) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + K.epsilon())
```

and I save the model with

```
        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
        optimizer= Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
        model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=dice_coef)
        model.summary()

        checkpointer = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('modelo_ia_1.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
        callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, monitor='val_loss')]


        results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.2, batch_size = 3, epochs = 50,       callbacks=callbacks)   #.fit: validation_split= [0.1] porcentaje del dataset destinado a validación
        model.save('modelo_ia_1.h5')
```

I know that having the function in the directory I can load the model as:

```
model = load_model(path,custom_objects={"dice_coef":dice_coef})
```

But I want to know if it's possible to SAVE the model with the custom metric in an .h5 file

I'm using tensorflow=2.10.1

I am new in Python programming and extremely new with tensorflow, so please be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.
Actually when you save the model with model.save('modelo_ia_1.h5') it will also save the metrics because you have compiled it with:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[dice_coef])
```

Later you just load you model and you can use your metrics like this:

```
model = load_model(path,custom_objects={"dice_coef":dice_coef})
loss, your_metric = model.eval(X_test, y_test)
```